# Deserialize JSON distinguising missing and null values

Tags: json, scala, play-json

I have a requirement to parse a JSON object, using play-json and distinguish between a missing value, a string value and a null value.

So for example I might want to deserialize into the following case class:

```
case class MyCaseClass(
  a: Option[Option[String]]
)
```

Where the values of 'a' mean:

- None - "a" was missing - normal play-json behavipr
- Some(Some(String)) - "a" had a string value
- Some(None) - "a" had a null value

So examples of the expected behavior are:

```
{}

should deserialize to myCaseClass(None)

{
  "a": null
} 

should deserialize as myCaseClass(Some(None))

{
  "a": "a"
}

should deserialize as myCaseClass(Some(Some("a"))
```

I've tried writing custom formatters, but the formatNullable and formatNullableWithDefault methods don't distinguish between a missing and null value, so the code I've written below cannot generate the Some(None) result

```
object myCaseClass {
  implicit val aFormat: Format[Option[String]] = new Format[Option[String]] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Option[String]] = {
      json match {
        case JsNull => JsSuccess(None) // this is never reached
        case JsString(value) => JsSuccess(Some(value))
        case _ => throw new RuntimeException("unexpected type")
      }
    }
    override def writes(codename: Option[String]): JsValue = {
      codename match {
        case None => JsNull
        case Some(value) =>  JsString(value)
      }
    }
  }

  implicit val format = (
      (__ \ "a").formatNullableWithDefault[Option[String]](None)
  )(MyCaseClass.apply, unlift(MyCaseClass.unapply))
}
```

Am I missing a trick here? How should I go about this?  I am very much willing to encode the final value in some other way than an Option[Option[Sting]] for example some sort of case class that encapsulates this:

```
case class MyContainer(newValue: Option[String], wasProvided: Boolean)
```

Comment: And, yes - I am aware that I could write an entirely custom read method for the entire object.  I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: Type `Option[Option[_]]` can hardly make any sensé whatever is the case. BTW I cannot see benefit from such `null`/missing distinction.

Comment: @cchantep .. there is a bit of a code smell for sure - but these are my requirements.  There is a somewhat plausible use case.  In any case its the json parsing that is the side i'm struggling with.  For the purpose of the question if we consider undefined and null to be separate values in json ... how do I parse that in play without just traversing the json myself.

Comment: You are assuming that undefined or null are différent, whereas they both the same using different format: represent the fact there is no value for a spécifiéd field

Comment: @cchantep ... but they fundamentally are different and have different properties in JavaScript, the language from which JSON was created.  Yes, it may be a code smell to consider them differently, but its strange that its so hard deal with a fundamental type in JSON in this framework.  One represents the enclosing object does not have that property, one, the property is defined but it has no value.

Comment: I have the requirement - whether its a good idea is moot.  Is it possible or not to do this is the question.

Comment: JSON doesn't have `undefined`

Comment: @AluanHaddad ...Well yes. Undefined would be the property doesn't exist / is not defined in the JSON object.

Comment: @iandotkelly quite so. I was just being pedantic about it.

Comment: i absolutely see `null` vs omitted as two completely different intents. it is unfortunate that there isn't less ambiguity about this in the JSON spec, but intuitively it makes sense to me to do what @iandotkelly is proposing here (especially when considering PATCH). I have opened a discussion about this with the core play-json team here: https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/distinguishing-between-omitted-and-null-values/7105

Answer (score 3):

I recently found a reasonable way to do this. I'm using Play 2.6.11 but I'm guessing the approach will transfer to other recent versions.

The following snippet adds three extension methods to `JsPath`, to read/write/format fields of type `Option[Option[A]]`. In each case a missing field maps to a `None`, a `null` to a `Some(None)`, and a non-null value to a `Some(Some(a))` as the original poster requested:

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

object tristate {
  implicit class TriStateNullableJsPathOps(path: JsPath) {
    def readTriStateNullable[A: Reads]: Reads[Option[Option[A]]] =
      Reads[Option[Option[A]]] { value =>
        value.validate[JsObject].flatMap { obj =>
          path.asSingleJsResult(obj) match {
            case JsError(_)           => JsSuccess(Option.empty[Option[A]])
            case JsSuccess(JsNull, _) => JsSuccess(Option(Option.empty[A]))
            case JsSuccess(json, _)   => json.validate[A]
                                             .repath(path)
                                             .map(a => Option(Option(a)))
          }
        }
      }

    def writeTriStateNullable[A: Writes]: OWrites[Option[Option[A]]] =
      path.writeNullable(Writes.optionWithNull[A])

    def formatTriStateNullable[A: Format]: OFormat[Option[Option[A]]] =
      OFormat(readTriStateNullable[A], writeTriStateNullable[A])
  }
}
```

Like previous suggestions in this thread, this method requires you to write out a JSON format in full using the applicative DSL. It's unfortunately incompatible with the `Json.format` macro, but it gets you close to what you want. Here's a use case:

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import tristate._

case class Coord(col: Option[Option[String]], row: Option[Option[Int]])

implicit val format: OFormat[Coord] = (
  (__ \ "col").formatTriStateNullable[String] ~
  (__ \ "row").formatTriStateNullable[Int]
)(Coord.apply, unlift(Coord.unapply))
```

Some examples of writing:

```scala
format.writes(Coord(None, None))
// => {}

format.writes(Coord(Some(None), Some(None)))
// => { "col": null, "row": null }

format.writes(Coord(Some(Some("A")), Some(Some(1))))
// => { "col": "A", "row": 1 }
```

And some examples of reading:

```scala
Json.obj().as[Coord]
// => Coord(None, None)

Json.obj(
  "col" -> JsNull, 
  "row" -> JsNull
).as[Coord]
// => Coord(Some(None), Some(None))

Json.obj(
  "col" -> "A", 
  "row" -> 1
).as[Coord]
// => Coord(Some(Some("A")), Some(Some(1)))
```

As a bonus exercise for the reader, you could probably combine this with a little shapeless to automatically derive codecs and replace the `Json.format` macro with a different one-liner (albeit one that takes longer to compile).

Comment: I wonder if this could be configured with `OptionHandlers` in the `JsonConfiguration`: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.0/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsonConfiguration.html

Answer (score 2):

Following @kflorence suggestion about OptionHandler I was able to get the desired behavior.

```
implicit def optionFormat[T](implicit tf: Format[T]): Format[Option[T]] = Format(
    tf.reads(_).map(r => Some(r)),
    Writes(v => v.map(tf.writes).getOrElse(JsNull))
  )

object InvertedDefaultHandler extends OptionHandlers {
  def readHandler[T](jsPath: JsPath)(implicit r: Reads[T]): Reads[Option[T]] = jsPath.readNullable

  override def readHandlerWithDefault[T](jsPath: JsPath, defaultValue: => Option[T])(implicit r: Reads[T]): Reads[Option[T]] = Reads[Option[T]] { json =>
    jsPath.asSingleJson(json) match {
      case JsDefined(JsNull) => JsSuccess(defaultValue)
      case JsDefined(value)  => r.reads(value).repath(jsPath).map(Some(_))
      case JsUndefined()     => JsSuccess(None)
    }
  }

  def writeHandler[T](jsPath: JsPath)(implicit writes: Writes[T]): OWrites[Option[T]] = jsPath.writeNullable
}

val configuration = JsonConfiguration[Json.WithDefaultValues](optionHandlers = InvertedDefaultHandler)

case class RequestObject(payload: Option[Option[String]] = Some(None))

implicit val requestObjectFormat: OFormat[RequestObject] = Json.configured(configuration).format[RequestObject]
```

```
Json.parse(""" {} """).as[RequestObject] // RequestObject(None)
Json.parse(""" {"payload": null } """).as[RequestObject] // RequestObject(Some(None))
Json.parse(""" {"payload": "hello" } """).as[RequestObject] // RequestObject(Some(Some(hello)))
```

So the important parts are:

- The `readHandlerWithDefault` basically flipping how
  `JsDefined(JsNull)` and `JsUndefined` are handling absent and explicit nulls compared to the original implementation in `OptionHandlers.Default`
- The JsonConfiguration taking both `Json.WithDefaultValues` and `optionHandlers`
- How the default value is being set. Note the RequestObject.payload's default value

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know how to achieve what you want automatically. For now it seems to me that you can't do that with the standard macro. However surprisingly you might achieve a similar result if you are OK with swapping the `null` and "absent" cases (which I agree is a bit confusing).

Assume class `Xxx` is defined as (default value is important - this will be the result for the `null` case)

```
case class Xxx(a: Option[Option[String]] = Some(None))
```

and you provide following implicit `Reads`:

```
implicit val optionStringReads:Reads[Option[String]] = new Reads[Option[String]] {
  override def reads(json: JsValue) = json match {
    case JsNull => JsSuccess(None) // this is never reached
    case JsString(value) => JsSuccess(Some(value))
    case _ => throw new RuntimeException("unexpected type")
  }
}

implicit val xxxReads = Json.using[Json.WithDefaultValues].reads[Xxx]
```

Then for a test data:

```
val jsonNone = "{}"
val jsonNull = """{"a":null}"""
val jsonVal = """{"a":"abc"}"""
val jsonValues = List(jsonNone, jsonNull, jsonVal)

jsonValues.foreach(jsonString => {
  val jsonAst = Json.parse(jsonString)
  val obj = Json.fromJson[Xxx](jsonAst)
  println(s"'$jsonString' => $obj")
})
```

the output is

> '{}' => JsSuccess(Xxx(Some(None)),)
>   
>  '{"a":null}' => JsSuccess(Xxx(None),)
>   
>  '{"a":"abc"}' => JsSuccess(Xxx(Some(Some(abc))),)

So

- absent attribute is mapped onto `Some(None)`
- `null` is mapped onto `None`
- Value is mapped onto `Some(Some(value))`

This is clumsy and a bit unexpected by a developer, but at least this distinguishes all 3 choices. The reason why `null` and "absent" choices are swapped is that the only way I found to distinguish those cases is to have the value in the target class to be declared as `Option` and with default value at the same time and in that case the  default value is what the "absent" case is mapped to; and unfortunately you can't control the value that `null` is mapped onto - it is always `None`.

Comment: Yeah ... I did consider that I might swap the null and undefined cases and achieve something like this.  Thanks for confirming this.